# Expected value of $X^n$

Tags: probability

Given: $F_X(x)$ is a CDF and: $E[X] = \int\limits_0^\infty (1-F_X (x))\, dx\ $

How do I prove: $E[X^n] = \int\limits_0^\infty nx^{n-1}(1-F_X(x))dx   $

Comment: Note that you need $X\ge 0$ for the first equation to hold. In this regime, the function $x \mapsto x^n$ is monotone. Can you then work out the cdf of $X^n$ in terms of that of $X$? If so, simply apply the first equality to $X^n$ and perform a substitution.

Comment: This process doesn't seem to get me the correct answer.

Comment: Byron's answer is of course correct, but it's curious that you didn't get the answer using the above. Are you sure you did the calculations correctly? Let $Y=X^n$. Unpacking the definition of $F_Y$, we have $F_Y(y) = P(X^n \le y) = P(X \le y^{1/n}) = F_X(y^{1/n})$ (here we're using that $X\ge 0$ a.s.). Thus, $$\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_Y(y))\,\mathrm{d} y = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(y^{1/n})) \,\mathrm{d} y .$$ Now use the substitution $u = y^{1/n}$ in the final integral, and the correct expression pops right out.

Answer (score 4):

The usual trick is to write $1-F_X(x)$ as an integral over the probability space $\Omega$ and use Fubini's theorem to exchange the order of integration.
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty n x^{n-1}P(X>x)\,dx&=&\int_0^\infty n x^{n-1}\int_\Omega {\bf 1}_{X(\omega)>x}\,P(d\omega)\,dx\\[5pt]
&=&\int_\Omega\int_0^\infty n x^{n-1} {\bf 1}_{X(\omega)>x}\,dx\,P(d\omega)\\[5pt]
&=&\int_\Omega\int_0^{X(\omega)} n x^{n-1} \,dx\,P(d\omega)\\[5pt]
&=&\int_\Omega  X(\omega)^n \,P(d\omega)\\[5pt]
&=&E(X^n).
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

Another way is recall that for a nonnegative random variable Y,
$E[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P[Y > t] dt.$

Then, for nonnegative random variable X and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have

\begin{align}
     E[X^n] &= \int_{0}^{\infty} P[X^n > t] dt\\
     &= \int_{0}^{\infty} P[X^n > x^n] nx^{n-1}dx\\
     &= \int_{0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} P[X > x] dx\\
\end{align}

Note: We have used the change of variable $t=x^n$, so $dt=nx^{n-1}dx$.

Q.E.D.